# how to partition totally to 14.04 after breaking original OSX

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, macbook

I have a MacBook 2,1 and must have messed up somewhere in the partitioning, because now I can't run the original OSX 10.6, which just gives me an error when I try to boot OSX from rEFIt.

I can run Ubuntu and I'm okay with this, but I want access to the rest of my hard drive while running Ubuntu. Rather than risk messing something up again, I've come to ask how to safely do that. Do I just use gparted again to delete the partition for OSX and increase the amount for Ubuntu?

Comment: did you created a separate partition for /home?

Comment: I shrunk the partition for OSX with Disk Utility, and OSX ran fine after that step. Then, I told Ubuntu to take the empty space. Since I don't know what you mean, I probably didn't.

Comment: I only created a partition for / when I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: What size partitions are we talking about?

Comment: 50gb for OSX, 30gb for Ubuntu. It's an old computer.

Comment: Would reinstalling Ubuntu just be my best bet?

Comment: One word: GParted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Os-Uninstller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller). Seems to be the easy way.